# OS X Yosemite does not show ToolBar icons when windows is displayed as sheet

Tags: objective-c, macos, icons, nstoolbaritem, osx-yosemite-beta

an `NSWindowController` loads its `NSWindow` from a XIB file. The windows uses a `NSToolBar` to offer some options. Nothing special so far.

Usually I use the following code to display the window as sheet:

```
settingsController = [[SettingsWindowController alloc] init]; 
[NSApp beginSheet:settingsController.window modalForWindow:self.window modalDelegate:nil didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
```

If I do this on Yosemite everything works fine, except that the toolbar does not show any icons. When I click on the toolbar where the icons *should* be the corresponding functions are started. Thus the toolbar items are there but not visible.

If the WindowController is called directly (not as sheet) everything works fine (including the icons):

```
[settingsController showWindow:nil];
```

Of course I know that Yosemite is still in beta. But if there is anything I can do on my end to solve/prevent this problem that would be much better than waiting for the final version and hoping that everything is fine there.

Does anyone know this issue? Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: If the same code works under 10.8/10.9 you should file a Radar